# Give CellIdendifier to Custom Cell from XIB

Tags: iphone, xib

I have created custom cell with xib.

```
NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
cell = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];
```

I want to give cell Identifier to it.
I tried

```
cell.reuseIdentifier=@"";
```

But its readonly property.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the table or cell in Interface Builder, you'll have to set the reuse identifier in Interface Builder, since this property get's set, when the object is created.
You can change (better: set) it programmatically only if you create the whole object programmatically and not in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"YourCellName";

YourCellName *cell = (YourCellName *) [tablview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourCellName" owner:self options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
            cell =  (YourCellName *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did         static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellForAlarm";
    
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
         NSLog(@"New");
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (CustomCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
new cell creatd wn scrol

Comment: I used your way but it created cell every time. From xib i gave identifier and it worked